# replace a x with headertext

Tags: replace, header, pq

I want to achieve the following in Power Query: in each cell, replace an x ​​with the text of the header:

Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5

y                             z
x         y         x                   x
          x         x         z
z         z         y         x         z
          x                   z         y
          x         z                   z
x         z         z                   x

This VBA code leads to the goal:

Option Explicit

Sub Replace_x()
   Dim rng As Range, c As Range
   Set rng = UsedRange  ' I know ...
   For Each c In rng
        If c = "x" Then c = Cells(1, c.Column).Value 'Row_1 = headers
Next c
End Sub

Do you have a solution for me?

Thanks and best regards
Guenther

Answer (score 0):

Guenther, this code solves your task:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, (cellValue)=> if cellValue = "x" then _ else cellValue}))
```

Where Source is Table with your data - you should make it on previous Query step(s)